# Does anyone know of any good sources on the algebraic theory of abelian varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties

I have a copy of Mumford's book, but as a final year undergraduate I am finding it to be a little too dense as a starting text. Something lighter would be appreciated to get an intuition before approaching Mumford and trying to tackle Mordell-Weil.

However, besides this book, every other reference I can find seems to concern itself with the analytic theory.

Answer (score 3):

There is a FANTASTIC book currently being written by Ben Moonen et. al. See [here](http://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/research.html#bookabvar). If you are very algebro-geometrically minded, this should be perfect for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good reference are the lecture notes of J.S. Milne on [Abelian Varieties](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf). The first chapter treats a lot of basic algebraic theory.

Comment: Great, thanks, I've had a quick look through and it appears like it may be helpful!